# how to show line without space in next line when screen gets smaller?

Tags: html, css

I have a big line without spaces, when screen gets smaller the text gets hidden on chrome is there any way to cut this  in next line, following is my code([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wBC9/))
HTML:

```
 <a href="http://www.findyogi.com/laptops/dell/allSpecs/f_price_28500:34500_page_0" target="_blank">http://www.findyogi.com/laptops/dell/allSpecs/f_price_28500:34500_page_0</a><br><br><br>

<a href="http://www.findyogi.com/laptops/dell/dell-inspiron-15-3521-ci3-4gb-500gb-linux-b942ed/price" target="_blank">http://www.findyogi.com/laptops/dell/dell-inspiron-15-3521-ci3-4gb-500gb-linux-b942ed/price</a>
```

it is working fine on firefox but some how not working on chrome. I am sure I am missing some CSS syles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your CSS in your fiddle and re-try it:

```
a {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```